# Can we use regex in symfony2 access control?

Tags: php, symfony

Can we use regex in access control in symfony2 security?

```
1) /foo/{id} -- [ROLE_ADMIN]
2) /foo/{id}/profile --  [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]
```

Another issue:

If I removed the access_control from my security, still it goes to the Security module and try to `Authenticate` from `Security/Authentication/Provider/AuthProvide`.

What should be the ideal behavior? I think it should not authenticate the resource if no `access_control` is in `security.yml`.

My firewall configuration is:

```
 firewalls:
    main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            myapp: true
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use regex.

But `/foo/{id}/profile` won't match what you want. As id is probably an integer, you'll have to use instead:

```
^/foo/[0-9]+/profile$
```

or

```
^/foo/[^/]+/profile$
```

Comment: I thought this wasn't working but I was being a bit dim, and was thwarted by the first-come-first-served routing order. Works a treat! Cheers +1